# 3-of-a-kind bonus in Ruk Shuk

Tags: rukshuk

In Ruk Shuk, can the 3-of-a-kind bonus be scored for using 3 white rocks?

And if so, do bridge rocks count as white rocks for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer, I've never played this but found rules online and seem fairly straight forward.

Yes the 3-of-a-kind bonus can be score with 3 white rocks.   This has bee confirmed by designer on the BGG forums [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/301702/3-kind-bonus)

As far I as I can tell from BGG pictures of the game, all bridge rocks are grey, not white.  Also looking at rules [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fl3u0pgfl6ewfe6/Rukshuk%20Rules.pdf) the bridge rocks are not even defined by a colour and just called 'bridge rock' as opposes to 'white rock', 'blue rock' etc so don't see why a bridge rock would could towards 3 white rocks.

Comment: In the set I have, the white rocks and the bridge rocks are exactly the same colour.   I thought the 3-of-a-kind bonus for white rocks was a bit weird as sometimes it means you are better off playing a white rock than playing a blue rock on a blue double bonus location,   but on the other hand I guess you could look at it as compensation for being "unlucky" and drawing many low-scoring rocks